# dlib implementation for linear_model.LinearRegression() of sklearn.linear_model

Tags: c++, scikit-learn, dlib

I have written python code which uses sklearn.linear_model . Our team uses c++ where my poc should become a part . How can I apply sklearn.linear_model in dlib library framework. http://dlib.net/ml.html

Comment: Sorry but asking for library recommendations is off-topic on SO: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.`

Comment: It is not "asking for library recommendations"

Comment: @AntonMalyshev .. I was asking for recommendation initially but I have edited my question to conform to the norms so that it's more relevant to the community in general .